# Quick way to calculate a confidence interval after changing dispersion parameter

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I'm teaching a modeling class in R.  The students are all SAS users, and I have to create course materials that exactly match (when possible) SAS output.  I'm working on the Poisson regression section and trying to match PROC GENMOD, with a "dscale" option that modifies the dispersion index so that the deviance/df==1.

Easy enough to do, but I need confidence intervals.  I'd like to show the students how to do it without hand calculating them.  Something akin to `confint_default()` or `confint()`

**Data**

```
skin_cancer <- data.frame(CASES=c(1,16,30,71,102,130,133,40,4,38,
                              119,221,259,310,226,65),
                      CITY=c(rep(0,8),rep(1,8)),
                      N=c(172875, 123065,96216,92051,72159,54722,
                          32185,8328,181343,146207,121374,111353,
                          83004,55932,29007,7583),
                      agegp=c(1:8,1:8))
skin_cancer$ln_n = log(skin_cancer$N)
```

**The model**

```
fit <- glm(CASES ~ CITY, family="poisson", offset=ln_n, data=skin_cancer)
```

**Changing the dispersion index**

```
summary(fit, dispersion= deviance(fit) / df.residual(fit)))
```

That gets me the "correct" standard errors (correct according to SAS).  But obviously I can't run `confint()` on a `summary()` object.

Any ideas?  Bonus points if you can tell me how to change the dispersion index within the model so I don't have to do it within the `summary()` call.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, and slightly deeper than it seems.

The simplest potential answer is to use `family="quasipoisson"` instead of poisson:

```
fitQ <- update(fit, family="quasipoisson")
confint(fitQ)
```

However, this won't let you adjust the dispersion to be whatever you want; it specifically changes the dispersion to the estimate R calculates in `summary.glm`, which is based on the Pearson chi-squared (sum of squared Pearson residuals) rather than the deviance, i.e.

```
sum((object$weights * object$residuals^2)[object$weights > 0])/df.r
```

You should be aware that `stats:::confint.glm()` (which actually uses `MASS:::confint.glm`) computes profile confidence intervals rather than Wald confidence intervals (i.e., this is not just a matter of adjusting the standard deviations).

If you're satisfied with Wald confidence intervals (which are generally less accurate) you could hack `stats::confint.default()` as follows (**note** that the `dispersion` title is a little bit misleading, as this function basically assumes that the original dispersion of the model is fixed to 1: this won't work as expected if you use a model that estimates dispersion).

```
confint_wald_glm <- function(object, parm, level=0.95, dispersion=NULL) {
    cf <- coef(object)
    pnames <- names(cf)
    if (missing(parm)) 
      parm <- pnames
    else if (is.numeric(parm)) 
      parm <- pnames[parm]
    a <- (1 - level)/2
    a <- c(a, 1 - a)
    pct <- stats:::format.perc(a, 3)
    fac <- qnorm(a)
    ci <- array(NA, dim = c(length(parm), 2L), dimnames = list(parm, 
                                                               pct))
    ses <- sqrt(diag(vcov(object)))[parm]
    if (!is.null(dispersion)) ses <- sqrt(dispersion)*ses
    ci[] <- cf[parm] + ses %o% fac
    ci
}

confint_wald_glm(fit)
confint_wald_glm(fit,dispersion=2)
```